# ImageResizer with AzureReader2 while hosted on GitHub Depoyed Azure Website throws 404s

Tags: azure-web-app-service, imageresizer

When I call use AzureReader to resize an image I get a 404, yet if I don't do a resize the passthrough call works perfectly.

I think it is due to the problem stated on the /resizer.debug.ashx page:

```
"Precompilation is enabled. Image providers may not work as expected."
```

The problem is I'm deploying through GitHub and don't know how to control precompilation.

So my question(s) are:
1. Am I right in thinking this is precompilation related? If not then what?
If so
2. how can I block precompilation on GitHub based deploy
3. how can I work around precompilation problem? (i've seen http://sunali.com/2008/01/09/virtualpathprovider-in-precompiled-web-sites/ but am not able to see how to apply to my problem)

On other point... incredibly similar code deployed fine to AAzure via Github 6 months ago and worked... has Azure Websites changed something with deployment in last 6 months or so?

Many thanks,

RIchard

Comment: Does the resize work if you run the website on your local machine? And what platform are you building your website on?

Comment: Hi @Zain, yes the website works locally. Just not when deployed to Azure Websites via GitHub. I'm running ASP.net MVC 4.

Environment information:

Running Microsoft-IIS/8.0 on Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0 and CLR 4.0.30319.19455
Trust level: Unrestricted
OS bitness: AMD64
Executing assembly: D:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
IntegratedPipeline: True

Comment: You can test whether or not it's precompilation related by deploying a precompiled version of the website on your local machine and see if the error occurs

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's VirtualPathProvider framework does not work in Precompiled mode.

Typically, this manifests as failure on direct access (without resizing).

However, AzureReader2 is unique among the blob providers in that it redirects to the original blob instead of directly serving the image when no changes are required.

You may be able to set `vpp=false` on the `<add name="AzureReader2 vpp="false"/>` element an get it to work.